# How can I make contents resize with when I fullscreen Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#

Please make your answers noob friendly as I am not great in Visual Studio just yet.

I'm working on a Visual Studio 2017 Windows Forms app, I've added every button's function close, fullscreen, minimize, but I've noticed when I go into fullscreen, the contents you stay where they were how can I make it resize based if I'm in fullscreen or not, like the custom close button I made stays on the middle of the top when I click Fullscreen, but when in "Normal" windowed mode it stays at the end of the app Pictures showing my problem "

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpiKc.jpg "

The first image is how I want it to be everywhere, second is how it is.

Also when I go fullscreen, it goes into windowed fullscreen, I want it to go into just windowed mode.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Look into anchors and/or the `Resize` event.

Comment: Make some experiments with anchoring and docking. Then, try the `TableLayoutPanel` and `FlowLayoutPanel` components.

Comment: Also understand the difference between content and controls.